# bokeh gridplot in streamlit

Tags: plot, bokeh, streamlit

I produced multiple plots (>40) which I want to display in a gridplot and on streamlit. I imagine something like:

```
grid_layout = gridplot([[None, plotList[1]], [plotList[3], plotList[4]]], plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
st.bokeh_chart(grid_layout)
```

However, this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This question was stated poorly. I thought there is a problem with the command, whereas the problem was with another part of the code, which I should have included.